# Openstack python-novaclient

Tags: python, openstack

I'm trying this toy code to initiate myself to the python-novaclient lib

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from novaclient.client import Client


   nova = Client(2, "####", "####", "####" , "####:8774/v2.0")
   _test = nova.images.list()

   print _test
```

but I always get this error:

[image]

does anyone know what kind of problem this could be?

Comment: If you try the CLI do you get images?

Comment: using the CLI tool you do this with: `nova image-list`

Comment: I get this message: **No handlers could be found for logger "keystoneclient.auth.identity.generic.base"
ERROR (InvalidResponse):**

Comment: I should have added that you need to properly source your environment variables before using the CLI tool to be able to authenticate against keystone first.

Comment: Create and source the OpenStack RC file followed the steps under **Create and source the OpenStack RC file** at this link http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/cli_openrc.html

Comment: great. Do you have keystone set up? Are you using a fully deployed openstack, or devstack?

Comment: No, I'm using the HTTP version of the API. I'm using a deployment of openstack with a node manager , a controller and tree compute nodes.

Comment: OK. Now, when you are using your Python script, can you confirm that you can at least successfully make any other nova calls? To at least validate that you are authenticating to keystone properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91917/discussion-between-giorgio-gambino-and-idjaw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the python-novaclient as a library and it was never designed to be used that way. It's a CLI that people unfortunately use as a library.

Give the official Python OpenStack SDK a try.

```
pip install openstacksdk
```

The code for listing images.

```
import sys

from openstack import connection
from openstack import profile
from openstack import utils

utils.enable_logging(True, stream=sys.stdout)

prof = profile.Profile()
prof.set_region(prof.ALL, "RegionOne")

conn = connection.Connection(
    auth_url='https://my.identity.endpoint/v2.0/',
    profile=prof,
    username="my_username",
    password="my_password")

for image in conn.compute.images():
    print(image)
```

More info that might be helpful too:

- http://python-openstacksdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openstacksdk

Answer (score 0):

you just need a good example, please refer to: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-novaclient/api.html

```
>>> from novaclient import client
>>> nova = client.Client(VERSION, USERNAME, PASSWORD, PROJECT_ID, AUTH_URL)
```

particularly, if your username is admin, password is password, project name is admin, keystone endpoint is http://127.0.0.1:5000, then it should be

```
>>> nova = client.Client(2, 'admin', 'password', 'admin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000')
```

note that auth url is keystone endpoint, NOT nova endpoint.